# Do we get billed for staging location for a google cloud dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Google Cloud Dataflow requires staging location for storing temp files for my dataflow job.

So far we have been executing Job which does not require much of third party jobs. Now we would like to execute a job which has many third party dependencies. So the files which will be uploaded on running the job is increased.

Do we billed for this staging location as well? 
Does Dataflow has multiple copies of a jar in staging location for every job execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you get billed for files in the GCS staging location according to normal [GCS billing rates](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Dataflow will check for a copy of the file in the staging location before uploading it. Dataflow uses a hash of the file contents to verify that the contents of a file in the staging location match what would be uploaded. If a matching file is found then Dataflow will use that file. So if multiple jobs are using the same staging location and the same jars, they will reuse the existing files in GCS and not create new versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One clarification, If a jar is not used due to the latest changes in a job(i.e. removed from classpath of a job), then will that jar be deleted by dataflow or it has to be deleted manually?

Comment: AFAIK Dataflow will not delete extra jar files in the staging directory. E.g. if you run two jobs, which share most of the classpath where one requires a particular jar and the other one doesn't, Dataflow won't delete the first job's extra jar when running the second job. Note that the GCS pricing is currently $0.026/GB/month (https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) - so most jars are not big enough for their storage cost to become significant.

Comment: How do you specify the same hash so that the staging file is reused everytime?